# Proving that $y\mapsto \chi(y)f(x,y) $ is globally Lipschitz in variables $y$ with $f$ Locally Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Assume $f:[a, b] \times \Bbb R\to \Bbb R $ is continuous and  satisfies the following condition:
$$\color{red}{\forall \eta \in \Bbb R,~\exists \ \delta = \delta(\eta)~,L(\eta)~\forall \ y_1, y_2 \in [\eta - \delta, \eta + \delta]\\\implies \lvert f(x, y_1) - f(x, y_2) \rvert \leq L\lvert y_1 - y_2 \rvert}~~\forall ~~x\in [a,b]$$  for  fixed $\eta\in\Bbb R$  we define 
$$\chi(y) =\begin{cases} 1&~~\text{if}~~|y-\eta| <\delta/2\\ 2-\frac{2}{\delta}|y-\eta|&~~\text{if}~~\delta/2\le |y-\eta| <\delta \\
0&~~\text{if}~~|y-\eta|\ge \delta \end{cases}$$

> Question: I would  like to prove  that,  $[a, b] \times \Bbb R \ni (x,y)\mapsto \chi(y)f(x,y)$ is Lipschitz in $y$ variables.

### Edit

I believe this may help: [Is a Lipschitz function differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609765/is-a-lipschitz-function-differentiable/2609787#2609787)

Comment: What are the $\eta$ and $\delta$ in the definition of $\chi$?

Comment: $\eta$ is fixed and $\delta =\delta(\eta)$ exists such that, the condition in red holds true.

Answer (score 0):

I will drop the argument $x$, as the assumption is uniform in $x$ anyway.

Let $g=\chi f$ and $I=[\eta - \delta, \eta + \delta]$. It is sufficient to show that $g$ is Lipschitz in $I$. Notice for example, if $M$ is a Lipschitz constant of $g$, $y_1 \notin I, y_2 \in I, y_1 < y_2$, then
$$ |g(y_1) - g(y_2)| = |g(\eta - \delta) + g(y_2) | \le M |\eta - \delta - y_2| \le M|y_1 - y_2|.$$

The short way: Using derivative a.e. and product rule, we obtain a.e.
$$ |g’| \le \frac2\delta \sup_{y\in I} |f(y)| + 1 \cdot L < \infty.$$
Thus, $g$ is Lipschitz.

The long way: use the definition.

Comment: Why is $g$ differentiable?

Comment: @GuyFsone it isn’t, it is only differentiable almost everywhere (as it is a product of Lipschitz continuous functions).

Comment: Now what happen when $x\in I$ and $y\not\in I$ ?

Comment: @GuyFsone $x$ is in $[a,b]$, not $I$. The assumption and statement is uniform in $x$. So just add $x$ into the proof. It won’t change anything. As for outside of $I$, the function $g$ is zero outside $I$, continuous, and Lipschitz on $I$. It is not hard to prove that $g$ is also Lipschitz on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Sorry sorry I meant What happens if have $y_1\in I$and  $y_2 \not \in I$

Comment: @GuyFsone I’ve extended the answer.